# Second order circuit initial conditions

Tags: circuit-analysis

I'm having trouble figuring out the response of this circuit, specifically the voltage across the capacitor in my homework. The input from the source is a unit step function, and there are no initial conditions for the capacitor or inductor.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fvzYYL.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

I first turned it into a norton equivalent, and used node analysis to arrive at the differential equation.

[image]

$$\frac{d^2}{dt}e_1+\frac{d}{dt}e_1(\frac{R_2}{L}+\frac{1}{R_1C})+e_1(\frac{1}{LC}+\frac{R_2}{CLR_1})=\frac{d}{dt}\frac{R_2}{C}I_1+\frac{R_2}{LC}I_1$$

I know that the solution to this equation takes the form:

$$ e_1(t) = Ae^{-\alpha t}cos(\omega_dt+\phi)$$

So I think my next step is to find A and phi by the following expressions:

$$e_1(0)= ?$$

$$\frac{d}{dt}e_1(0) = ?$$

However, I am a bit unsure about how exactly to go about this. My reasoning suggests that they are both 0 - at the moment the source switches from 0v to 1v, the capacitor is a short circuit and the inductor is an open circuit. So all the current flows through the capacitor, and there is no voltage drop since the current source is shorted - so \$e_1 = 0\$ and \$e_1'=0\$. However, this means that A and phi are also both zero, so this is confusing for me. Can someone give me some help with finding A and phi?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the instant of switch on, the capacitor is the dominant impedance and therefore the voltage across it (e1) is zero however it will be rising at a non-zero rate: -

[image]

As you can see, the charging voltage rate (dv/dt) equals I/C where I is the current source in your modified circuit (or V1/R1 in your original circuit).

Comment: Yes, I think I see what you mean - let me try this out and I'll get back to you.

Comment: This did work for me - but I had a general follow-up. To determine the initial conditions, should I replace the inductors with an open and the capacitor with a short and then consider voltage and current through the capacitor?

Comment: The inductor is effectively an open circuit at start up and for the capacitor it's just the regular shape of the exponential curve right at t(0)+ that is considered.

Answer (score 0):

If the capacitor and inductor have zero initial energy conditions, then the voltage across the capacitor Vc at t = 0 would be 0V since the capacitor is shorted. **Note that this is only true for zero initial energy conditions.**

If it does not state that, then you would have to solve for continuity variables (i.e. Vc and iL where iL is the current through the inductor) at t=0. After getting those, solve the circuit for t>0.

Although, does it state that the circuit is in DC steady state at t = 0-? If yes, then it should be helpful in finding Vc(0). If no, are there any statements regarding the ckt or what you told us is just that?

Comment: I forgot to mention, there are no initial conditions in the circuit (post updated to reflect this)

Comment: You could assume that the circuit has zero initial conditions, and compare your answer to perhaps a solution key?

Answer (score -1):

\$e_1(0)=0\$

\$\frac{d}{dt}e_1(0)=\frac{V1}{R1C1}\$  from \$\frac{dV}{dt}=Ic/C\$  and \$Ic=V1/R1\$ after t=0

Comment: I answered your question on initial conditions. whoever thinks otherwise is incorrect (-1). next question? The step input defines e1(t)=0 for T<0, the capacitor voltage rises as does the inductor current , the next question is the Q , overshoot and resonant frequency of the step response.